# CLion Macro Rearrangement

Tags: c, clion

I use a library called e4c in a C project, which allows try...catch syntax in C. However, CLion rearrange function always messes the indentation.

Is there any way to tell CLion to rearrange code before macro substitution?

edit:

For example, when the following code is rearranged:

```
try {

} catch (RuntimeException) {
}
```

It gives:

```
try {

        } catch (RuntimeException) {
        }
```

Because the try catch expand to 2 ifs and a while loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "rearrange function"? Can you show some example of actual and expected code, before and after this "rearranging"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `try` and `catch` are macros, so you can find that the formatting is correct after the macros substitution.
You can mention your case in [CLion tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2289)